# creating pages in symfony 2 - template exception

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to run my first template in symfony 2 according to "Optional Step 3: Create the Template" from the book but I get an exception: `Warning: filemtime() [<a href='function.filemtime'>function.filemtime</a>]: stat failed for C:\Server\Apache2\htdocs\SymfonyProject\src\Acme\HelloBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig in C:\Server\Apache2\htdocs\SymfonyProject\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\Loader\FilesystemLoader.php line 68`

Previous steps from the book work so I have no idea what is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you delete an existing twig template, the framework will throw the error you've described. You need to clear your cache, even in the dev environment: `php app/console cache:clear`

Comment: This is only for dev environment, needs to run also with --env=prod for the production one.

Comment: Or just `rm -rf app/cache/*` ;)